# Using Service Worker - MVC view that uses fetched data when online

Tags: asp.net-mvc, service-worker

I am using the Service Worker example on [this](https://www.spheregen.com/implementing-pwa-behavior-to-asp-net-mvc-5-apps/) page.  I have implemented the service worker (ASP.NET MVC application running within an SSL localhost site) and I receive confirmation (console message) that it is registered.

Within the URL's to cache I have added

- an index page (MyController/Index) which performs a "fetch" (part of the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API))
- as well as the URL that is fetch'd (MyController/GetData) which goes
  and gets the data from the database

All looks OK when I am online - i.e. all pages I have specified in the URLs to cache are all successfully retrieved (as per the Chrome|DevTools|Network tab).

When I go offline (via the Chrome|DevTools|Application|Service-Workers|Offline checkbox), if I go to pages that I have *not* listed in the URL's to cache, I get the "Offline" page I have specified in the service worker (which is correct).  However when I navigate to the Index page (MyController/Index - mentioned above) which I have listed in the URL's to cache, the view appears however the "fetch" (to MyController/GetData) on that page fails - I wondered what the expected result of this is.

I was of the assumption that the data (retrieved through MyController/GetData) would be cached and when I go offline that cached data would be substituted if the fetch failed (i.e. the NetworkFirst strategy)

Can anyone point me in the direction of what should occur and ideally an MVC example

Comment: From what I understand from your question, you are successfully able to get to your `MyController/Index` page but fail on the subsequent`'MyController/GetData`. My guess is the conditions of the `GetData` request do not match the conditions found in the fetch handler as you expect. You can validate this by debugging the fetch handler in your developer console in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justin was right - my MyController/GetData method was actually using a 'Post' method and in my fetch handler it was attempting to always fetch non-Get requests from the network - hence the failure when offline.  I just changed the request to a Get request and my service worker fallback logic got the data from cache